# Restriction on margin/padding for the 'Div' and 'Article' tag in 'Hero section'

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I've recently been getting into web development and I'm currently working on a project with tailwind but I can't seem to add any margin to my `article` and `div` in the 'Hero section'.

On the `img` tag all the way down I can add "mb-12" but can't add any higher value than the 12. Same on the header, I can add a "mb-12" which would satisfy my layout for the 'Hero Section', but can't go any higher than that.

I just wanna know **why** and **what's** restricting it from giving it a higher value than '12'.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="font-html">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
    <title>Hero</title>
  </head>
  <body
    class="bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-700 via-gray-600 to-slate-700 dark:bg-gradient-to-r dark:from-gray-900 dark:via-neutral-950 dark:to-slate-900 antialiased text-white min-h-screen"
  >
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <header
      class="sticky top-0 z-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-700 via-gray-600 to-slate-700 dark:bg-gradient-to-r dark:from-gray-900 dark:via-neutral-950 dark:to-slate-900 mb-12"
    >
      <section class="flex justify-between items-center p-8 max-w-4xl mx-auto">
        <h1
          class="text-4xl font-bold transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
        >
          <a href="#hero">Manga<span class="text-indigo-300">Verse</span></a>
        </h1>

        <div>
          <button
            id="mobile-btn"
            class="md:hidden text-3xl font-medium mr-2 focus:outline-none"
          >
            &#9776;
          </button>
          <nav class="hidden md:block space-x-8 font-medium text-lg ">
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="#login"
              >Login</a
            >
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="#signup"
              >Sign Up</a
            >
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="#login"
              >About</a
            >
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="#contact"
              >Contact</a
            >
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
    </header>

    <!-- Hero Section -->

    <main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto">
      
      <div
        id="hero"
        class="flex items-center justify-center flex-col-reverse md:flex-row gap-2"
         
      >
        <article class="md:w-1/2">
          <h2 class="font-bold text-4xl max-w-4xl text-center sm:text-5xl">
            Start Your <span class="text-indigo-300">Adventure</span>.
          </h2>
          <h2 class="font-bold text-4xl max-w-4xl text-center sm:text-5xl">
            Explore the Manga<span class="text-indigo-300">Verse</span>!
          </h2>
        </article>
        <img
          class="md:w-1/2 h-auto mb-12 block w-[480px]"
          src="img/newToji.png"
          alt="Toji Fushiguro"
        />
       
      </div>
      <hr class="w-1/2 mx-auto">
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Tailwind are you using and how are you actually using it (e.g. CDN, bundler, CSS file, script)? Also, what values are you trying apart from mb-12?

Comment: You should be able to go as high as mb-96 with v3 and also use arbitrary values that go past this value, e.g. mb-[120px]

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.0 and installed it with Tailwind CLI but somehow it works now even though I still have no clue why that was happening. Still, thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>`, `<img>` and all HTML tags.